# Windows 10's HomeGroup Share media under "Recorded TV" rather than Videos & Normal Folder Sharing

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-media-player, homegroup, sharing

I used to be able to set this up in Windows 7 but cannot find out how to do it in Windows 10.

Basically I am wanting my TV Shows to appear under "Recorded TV" in the Homegroup rather than under "Videos"

Currently my "Videos" has both TV & Movies under it because I cannot find a way to separate them and make the library populate.

My Windows Media Player has the "Recorded TV" link on the left and I have clicked on Organise > Manage > Recorded TV and added the library locations but for some reason it doesn't pull in the episodes even though on "Videos" when I do that for movies it works fine...

If you look at:

[image]

You can see that it is setup but  there are no items in the recorded TV library...

Comment: When you look at the individual files does it look like they inherited the same permissions?  It is difficult to tell if you are showing the permissions to the parent folder or the file you are trying to share.  I don't see the HomeUsers or the everyone group on the last picture on the right, so the files might not have inherited the permissions from the parent shared folder.

Comment: The last picture is the same folder, I'm just showing you all of the permissions for that folder. So it has plenty of permissions all with full control. The individual files/folders inside the folder that I have shared (that I cannot access) all have the same permissions as the main folder. The last *two* pictures are the same folder just from the simple view and the advanced view to make it clear that it has permissions set.

Answer (score 0):

A note about NTFS permissions when used with Sharing permissions:

> When using share permissions and NTFS permissions together, if there
>   is a conflict in the configuration, the most restrictive permission
>   prevails

http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-combined.htm

That means if your red X'ed administrators, or no a missing homegroup is trying to access a shared permissions file the NTFS permissions will deny it if it is included in the last picture on the right.  Appearing to have share access, but then will be denied.  I believe this is what is happening.  It is hard to tell with all the redaction.  Your screen shots are only showing permissions for one account at a time, and to assume they are the same across all accounts would be stupid on my part.  You may need to add Everyone or Homegroup to that final folder on the right in the picture, or you may just need to correct an NTFS permission on an existing account.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178.aspx

Comment: Black = Folder Name/Location, Green = Username (Musselman) or PC Name (Muasselman-PC)